# Moving Watson Assistant project from one IBM account to another?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm trying to move my Watson Assistant project from one account to another and I'm struggling to figure out how to export the data and logs to begin working on this project from my colleagues IBM account.

Do you know how I can do this and will all the statistics and history still be available in the new account?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "new experience", [backup and restore is discussed here in the Watson Assistant documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-admin-backup-restore). Similar [information on backup / restore is available for the Classic Watson Assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-backup).

Do not expect to have an entirely, fully identical instance. I would recommend to check the [topic on failover options](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-admin-failover). It discusses what makes up a deployed in-use assistant.